# Is there a way to have an Ember link-to helper fire on keyPress?

Tags: ember.js, accessibility

I am in the process of getting our product to WCAG 2.0.  I know with actions I can specify that it fire `on="keyPress"`.  Before I start replacing all of our link-to's with actions, is there support for specifying link-to events?  I haven't happened across anything hinting at it in the docs.

Edit: The link-to's I'm having issues with have a `tagName` that is different from an anchor.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41702645/is-there-a-way-to-have-an-ember-link-to-helper-fire-on-keypress

Comment: if you go for this kind of customization, then I would say grab the url using `href-to` helper from [ember-href-to](https://github.com/intercom/ember-href-to) addon and apply it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you need to change? `link-to` renders as a regular old anchor which is keyboard  accessible by default.

Comment: Ah, you bring up an excellent point @steveax- it's where I'm specifying a tagName that's not an anchor that I'm running into issues.

Answer (score 2):

Consider passing `eventName` property to link-to component.

```
{{#link-to 'users' eventName='mouseEnter'}} Users {{/link-to}}
```

This will transitionTo users route when mouse over the link-to element.

Note: I am not sure how do you use keyPress event for link-to component

Comment: In testing this on some link-to's that have a tagName assigned to a table row, it's interesting that the mouse events work while specifying a key event does not.  I'm going off of this list: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/components/handling-events/#toc_event-names.  This is still super handy, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm reworking my markup so that the link-to's to use their default tagName (a), which solves my problem. This isn't the accepted answer as the issue still remains that when you use a tagName that is different than the default, there doesn't appear to be a way to transition on key events.  My primary use case is working with link-to's as table rows.

Comment: Just a thought, and I haven't tested this, but did you try giving the `<tr>` a role of [link](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#link)? This does of course violate [the first rule of aria](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-aria-in-html-20150521/#first-rule-of-aria-use) and going with the default tag name is better, but it may do what you want.